# How to cache permission and role?

Tags: php, laravel-5, entrust

I use https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust
Because to many same requests  [image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question? Its quite unclear what you are asking at this point

Comment: You can implement redis cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add
'ttl' => 30 //In minutes in cache.php

and in .env

CACHE_DRIVER=array